# Проблема с установкой значения для переменной (PHP)

Tags: php

Объявляю я 2 переменные так:

```
$phone;
$mail;
```

Дальше, если выполняется условие, то переменным задаются эти значения:

```
$phone = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($db, "SELECT phone FROM accounts WHERE id = '$id'"))['phone'];
        $mail = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($db, "SELECT mail FROM accounts WHERE id = '$id'"))['mail'];
```

А использую я их так:

```
mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE accounts SET login = '$login', password = '$pass', mail = '$mail', phone = '$phone' WHERE id = '$id'");
```

Все вместе выглядит так:

```
$phone;
$mail;
if(!$binding == ""){
  //Код
}else{
        $phone = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($db, "SELECT phone FROM accounts WHERE id = '$id'"))['phone'];
        $mail = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($db, "SELECT mail FROM accounts WHERE id = '$id'"))['mail'];
}
mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE accounts SET login = '$login', password = '$pass', mail = '$mail', phone = '$phone' WHERE id = '$id'");
```

Ошибка в том, что переменным не задаются значения (как мне кажется, потому что значения задаются внутри условия и после закрытия скобок они вновь исчезают). Как это можно исправить? Если мое предложение верно - то вариант просто поместить mysql запрос внутрь условия (где задаются значения переменным) - мне не подходит в моей ситуации (тк этот запрос должен находиться именно в конце кода поверх почти всех остальных условий). Сомневаюсь, что все понятно объяснил, так что если что не понятно - разъясню подробнее, заранее извиняюсь за неточность.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не правильно объявили переменные. Правильно будет так:

```
$phone = 0;
$mail = '';
```

Т.е., для строковых переменных при объявлении сохранять в переменную строку нулевой длины, а для числовых - соответственно 0.

---

И ещё, вы подставляете переменные прямо в строку sql-запроса, и тем самым получаете уязвимость:

> ***SQL-инъекция*** — это атака, направленная на веб-приложение, в ходе которой конструируется SQL-выражение из пользовательского ввода путем простой конкантенации ( например, `$query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=".$_REQUEST["id"]` )

Используйте подготовленные запросы [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)
или [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepared-statements.php)